# How to bound a google map between two location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my application i have two drop down boxes first box had origin 
second box had destination list. My question is how to bound a map between two position.

For an example if i select  UK in the origin box Tokyo in the destination box . The resultant map must show both country like that
the resultant map dynamically change the map zoom level also

Please suggest me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have their longitude and latitude values , and you should put them in your JS variable which stores them, here is an example : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/